# Is my data secure?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, security

My Android phone was recently stolen, so will the thief have access to all my pictures in the thumbnail folder? I have hidden the pictures in an app called Vaulty so will they still be visible in Thumbnail folder (I mistakenly removed the file manager from my phone a day before the phone was stolen)? Please help me out with this ! :(

Answer (score 2):

If your memory card is not encrypted then your images and other data is not safe from the thief. Vaulty simply *hides* files, not protect and encrypt them.

But then again, most thieves are only after the money. Mostly likely they will find a way to reformat your phone, delete all contents, and sell it as refurbished/used on ebay.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what about the Thumbnail folder? the pictures that were deleted and the ones that are in Vaulty, will they be found in the Thumbnail folder if the thumbnail folder was not cleared? considering that the thief is not a techie will he get access to them by just connecting the card to some other computer?

Comment: Yes, cache cleaners are the only apps that I know of that empties those thumbnail folders.

Answer (score 0):

If you think the phone might still be on / not deactivated, you could try installing [Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb&hl=en) from Lookout Mobile. There are other apps that you can remotely load and wipe your memory card remotely so the thief cannot access your photos. However if the thief has since removed your memory cad, he can unfortunately access your photos.